# I can't upload an image from the clipboard

Tags: support, images, error-message, image-upload

Not sure whether this is the right place. If I try to upload an image (pasted from clipboard or from the file sys), an error is raised.

```
{"Success":false,"Error":5,"ErrorMessage":"Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"}
```

```
curl 'https://stackoverflow.com/upload/image?method=json' \
  -H 'authority: stackoverflow.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hr;q=0.8' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryZsLdJJK5oxxzUlxE' \
  -H 'cookie: ...' \
  -H 'origin: https://stackoverflow.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  --data-raw $'------WebKitFormBoundaryZsLdJJK5oxxzUlxE\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="stackoverflow.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZsLdJJK5oxxzUlxE\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="fkey"\r\n\r\n41199ce7159cxxxxxxxe1fdf29106bc4116315a203e5c06abe5b2c40bb0f\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZsLdJJK5oxxzUlxE--\r\n' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: same issue for the drag & drop. Edit: it seems to be a general issue whatever the upload method

Comment: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

Comment: Just tried doing this. [Happened to me as well](https://imgur.com/a/gIniJCx). Note: Imgur is still working, so this is probably a Stack Exchange thing.

Comment: Sigh, they said it was fixed (and for a moment, it was, FWIW)

Comment: Related new report on MSE: ["Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server" is back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382916)